# Hibernate Validation i18n (Japanese) are not displayed well (Garbled)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc

Validation works as expected but messages are displayed well only in English. I use my own messages for Japanese.

Problem is that I get garbled validation messages for Japanese. I am using validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar with hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final.jar.
I have ValidationMessages.properties and ValidationMessages_ja.properties.
Files are utf8:
For example:
firstName=姓をご記入ください。comes out: å½ãé¸æãã¦ãã ããã

I use in the bean above an attribute to be validated:
@Size(min = 1, message = "{myErrorMsg}")
private String myAttribute;

In my spring.xml:

```
    <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <!-- <property name="basename" value="classpath:tc-messages" /> -->
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:tc-messages</value>
            <value>classpath:ValidationMessages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

and:

```
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver">
    <!-- <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_us" /> -->
</bean>
```

Anything I am missing?

Thanks,
Rod

Comment: Did you find a solution for your question ? I am stucl with the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the encoding is probably lost at build time. Is the build tool you use aware of your file encoding? For example, with Maven, you need this property:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

Comment: Setting this property does not help to resolve the issue